# How to disable auto login for Windows network drives

Tags: windows

How to disasble the auto login for Windows shared drives.

My requirement is that I have to use multiple user names for the same shared drive. Right now it is caching the logins and not allowing the others.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is probably a SuperUser.com question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using alternative names, including the IP addresses, for some of your credentials.

Windows is smart: it doesn't want you accessing the same server with different credentials, because that complicates keeping track of what connections have what credentials.  Fortunately, Windows is stupid: it keeps track of this by server name.

So if your server has two or more names, you can use more than one set of credentials with it, concurrently.

Example: suppose you have a server named 'server'.  If it has a second name, like "fileserver", you can have concurrent connections as:

```
net use \\server\fileshare /username:domain\user1
net use \\fileserver\fileshare /username:domain\user2
```

You can also use the IP address of the server for a third set of credentials:

```
net use \\a.b.c.d\fileshare /username:domain\user3
```

Comment: Perhaps mention net use /delete as well to remove the "cache" and get to reauthenticate

Comment: I have used names and IP's for a similar setup.  I have also used the command NET USE \\servername /delete in a batch file when needed to delete permissions.  It isnt ideal, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can only establish one session per server, so only one user name can access a server at any one time from the same machine.

Examples:

SUCCESS: net use \server1\fileshare1 /user:domain\user1 /p:n

SUCCESS: net use \server2\fileshare1 /user:domain\user2 /p:n

FAILURE: net use \server1\fileshare2 /user:domain\user2 /p:n
[user1 is already connected to server1; disconnect the session for user1 if you want user2 to have access].